# Is it safe to transfer files onto the computer from the Raspberry pi sd card, and then put it back later?

Tags: sd-card

I would like to try other distributions sometime, but I only have one sd card. I am talking about cutting and pasting, not copying.

Comment: You might want to look into rsync for some handy features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This should be very straightforward and I would not expect you to have any issues.

Comment: Specifically, under Linux you would use dd to create an image of the SD card that you would write back later, e.g. `dd if=/dev/sdX of=card.img`. Under Windows this can be done using win32diskimager which should be intuitive.

Comment: @Fred He only wants to copy and paste individual files, not all (or sections) of the filesystem.

Comment: Ah, I missed the 'files' in the question title. By USB key is probably the easiest way to do that. Plugging the SD card in directly and mounting is trivial under Linux, but a little complex under Windows due to ext3/ext4 (filesystem). You could I suppose copy to the /boot partition though.

Answer (score 2):

If your SD-Card is big enough, you might want to take a look at BerryBoot.
This way you can have multiple OS's on the same Card.

http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot